# Data from two tables filtered by a column

Tags: mysql, inner-join

In MySQL, I have a `myTab1` which has columns like `userId`, `name`, `gender`, `birthMonth`. Here `userId` is the  primary key.
There can be only 1 unique `userId` in the entire table.

I have another table `myTab2` which has columns like `userId`, `level`, `score`.
There is no primary key in this table and it is just for the transactions.

Example:

`myTab1`

| userId | name | gender | birthMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | name1 | Male | January |
| xyz | name2 | Female | March |
| mno | name3 | Male | July |

`myTab2`

| userId | level | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 10 |
| abc | 2 | 9 |
| abc | 3 | 11 |
| abc | 4 | 10 |
| abc | 5 | 23 |
| xyz | 1 | 11 |
| xyz | 2 | 10 |
| mno | 1 | 8 |

Now I need only the top 3 users with the highest level along with their name which is in myTab1 as below

| userId | name | level | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | name1 | 5 | 23 |
| xyz | name2 | 2 | 10 |
| mno | name3 | 1 | 8 |

Following is what I wrote but not sure how to get the result like above. I am not good at DB queries and looking for some help.

```
SELECT 
b.*, 
a.name 
FROM 
myTab1 AS b 
INNER JOIN myTab2 as a ON b.userId=a.userId 
ORDER BY level DESC 
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
SELECT
    t1.userId,
    t1.name,
    MAX(t2.level) AS level,
    MAX(t2.score) AS score
FROM
    myTab1 t1
JOIN
    myTab2 t2 ON t1.userId = t2.userId
GROUP BY
    t1.userId, t1.name
ORDER BY
    level DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Output

[image]